# php - rewrite url with dynamic host name

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I need to rewrite url with rule like below

```
RewriteRule ^files/([a-z0-9-\.]+)$ files/domain.com/$1
```

domain.com is current host name. It is dynamic (don't ask why plz). So I can not do like this. Anyway, how I can get current host name and put it like this:

```
RewriteRule ^files/([a-z0-9-\.]+)$ files/{{ current host name with out www. }}/$1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)(.*)$
RewriteRule ^files/(a-z0-9-\.]+)$ files/%2/$1
```

Can't test either, but it should be something like this. (www\.) makes sure with or without www it works, then the (.*) part in the HTTP_HOST captures the rest of the domain. By using %2 this domain is later re-used in the new request.

Comment: I think it should be RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.*)$

Answer (score 4):

`%{HTTP_HOST}` will give you the requested host name.

I can't test right now whether it can be used in a `RewriteRule`, but I think it can.

Answer (score 3):

As already mentioned, `%{HTTP_HOST}` contains the value of the [*Host* header field](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.23).

You can use the following to always get only the last two domain levels:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+\.[^.]+)$
RewriteRule ^files/([a-z0-9-\.]+)$ files/%1/$1
```

Comment: This one is the best, it's probably (a bit) faster than both, and also more secure than mine.

Comment: Very nice solution, but be cautious if you may run across a domain with more than two significant levels (for example, blog.example.com).

Comment: Hmm, hadn't thought of that. This one will load /domain.com/ regardless of the subdomain, mine would load /blog.subdomain.com/

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+\.[^.]+)$
RewriteRule ^files/([a-z0-9-\.]+)$ files/%1/files/$1
RewriteRule ^templates/([a-z0-9_ \.-]+)$ files/%1/templates/$1 When I put a new rule line for templates, both won't work any more include rule 1 (files)?

Comment: @complez: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+\.[^.]+)$ RewriteRule ^(files|templates)/([a-z0-9-\.]+)$ files/%1/$1/$`

Answer (score 1):

I think this might do the trick for you:

```
RewriteRule ^files/([a-z0-9-\.]+)$ files/%{SERVER_NAME}/$1
RewriteRule ^files/www\.([^/]+)/([a-z0-9-\.]+)$ files/$1/$2
```

(The second line removes any www. from the domain.)